# Таблица Sqlite разбивает строку на символы

Tags: python, sqlite, telebot

Я делаю Телеграмм бота на Telebot и когда я пытаюсь добавить строку в бд, её добавляет, но разделённую на символы.

[image: Это код]

[image: Вот так добавляет строку бд]

[image: Как должно добавлять]

Буду очень благодарен если поможете решить эту проблему

Comment: [Пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119/#12120) Добавьте текстом в вопрос (кнопка [edit])

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вы знаете как работает [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany)?
В вашем случае [executemany](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.executemany) на каждый символ строки создавал запрос `INSERT INTO`, который передавался в поле `disc`

Если вам нужно вставить одну строку в базу, то используйте просто [execute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute), но оберните `textdb` в кортеж или список:

```
cursor.execute("<ваш sql запрос>", (textdb,))
```

---

**PS.**

У [`execute(sql, parameters=())`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) второй параметр принимает кортеж, но ему на самом деле сойдет любой объект с поддержкой итерацией (строки тоже подходят из-за чего, если передавать как есть, то код поведет себя не так как ожидалось). Поэтому, нужно было обернуть `textdb` в кортеж на 1 элемент `(textdb,)` - тут важна запятая, т.к. в случаи `(textdb)` это не будет кортежом.

*Если несколько параметров передавать, то это выглядит адекватнее, типа: `cursor.execute("<ваш sql запрос (?, ?, ?)", (textdb, result, abc))`*

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @Константин, пожалуйста, и не забудьте выполнить мои рекомендации по коду вопроса и [проголосовать + принять мой ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)